# Which SAS Cable is required for to connect SAS drive to RAID controller

Tags: sas, cable

I have two 2.5" SAS drives which have a SFF-8482 connector. I also have an LSI 9211-8i controller card, as well as a TYAN motherboard with a SAS controller. Both of these controllers use the SFF-8087 mini clip.

My motherboard comes with several 4 channel forward breakout cables with sata connectors on one end and SFF-8087 connector on the other end.

Could I hookup my two SAS drives with a male to male SATA adapter and one of [these](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816115101&nm_mc=OTC-Froogle&cm_mmc=OTC-Froogle-_-Server%20-%20Accessories-_-HighPoint%20Technologies%20%20Inc.-_-16115101) cables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option for you would be to get a SFF-8087 to 4x SFF-8482 cable (Robin links to one in his "answer") but there are plenty around. The cable you linked could not be used directly, as it has standard SATA style connections that your cards would not accept (though you could add another converter in there, it's best not to do so).

Normal SATA cables can not be plugged into SAS drives. SAS drives have a SFF-8482 connection (which is very similar, but) with a 2nd data port in between the primary data port and power ports (the primary data and power are in the same place as a SATA drive). This second port "keys" SAS drives so you can't plug them into a SATA cable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only lead you should need is one of these, http://www.cleverboxes.com/p-109534-lsi00179-lsi-sff8087-to-4x-sff8482-cable-1m.aspx, but your reply sounds like you already have one. (I'm assuming your power supply has enough SATA power connectors)

The only purpose I can see for the cable you linked is if you only have spare molex type power connectors rather than SATA, then that cable will convert the power connectors for you.